# Arrays: Find minimum number of swaps to make bitonicity of array minimum?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose we are given an array of integer. All adjacent elements are guaranteed to be distinct. Let us define *bitonicity* of this array `a` as `bt` using the following relation:

```
bt_array[i] = 0, if i == 0;
            = bt_array[i-1] + 1, if a[i] > a[i-1]
            = bt_array[i-1] - 1, if a[i] < a[i-1]
            = bt_array[i-1], if a[i] == a[i-1]

bt = last item in bt_array
```

We say the bitonicity of an array is *minimum* when its bitonicity is 0 if it has an odd number of elements, or its bitonicity is +1 or -1 if it has an even number of elements.

The problem is to design an algorithm that finds **the fewest number of swaps** required in order to make the bitonicity of any array minimum. The time complexity of this algorithm should be at worst O(n), n being the number of elements in the array.

For example, suppose `a = {34,8,10,3,2,80,30,33,1}`

Its initial `bt` is -2. Minimum would be 0. This can be achieved by just 1 swap, namely swapping 2 and 3. So the output should be 1.

Here are some test cases:

> Test case 1: a = {34,8,10,3,2,80,30,33,1}, min swaps = 1 ( swap 2 and  3)
>
> Test case 2: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}: min swaps = 2 (swap 7 with 4 and 6 with 5)
>
> Test case 3: {10,3,15,7,9,11}: min swaps = 0. bt = 1 already.

And a few more:

> {2,5,7,9,5,7,1}: current `bt` = 2. Swap 5 and 7:  minSwaps = 1
>
> {1,7,8,9,10,13,11}: current `bt` = 4: Swap 1,8 : minSwaps = 1
>
> {13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}: current `bt` = -12: Swap (1,6),(2,5) and (3,4) : minSwaps = 3

---

I was asked this question in an interview, and here's what I came up with:

```
1. Sort the given array.
2. Reverse the array from n/2 to n-1.
3. Compare from the original array how many elements changed their position. 
   Return half of it.
```

And my bit of code that does this:

```
int returnMinSwaps(int[] a){
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int[] b = a;
    Arrays.sort(b);
    for(int i=0; i<= b.length/2 - 1; i++){
        swap(b[b.length - i], b[b.length/2 - i]);
    }
    int minSwaps = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            minSwaps++;
    }
    return minSwaps/2;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting correct minimum number of ways for some test cases using this logic. Also, I am sorting the array which is making it in `O(n log n)` and it needs to be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: One flaw I am finding in your algo is.. It will say 1 swap is required for a = {2,1} but it's bitonicity is -1 so no swap is required. So basically, You will have to take minbetween asnwers after sorting in decreasing order and increasing order.

Comment: @KautsyaKanu But wouldn't it be more or less same? For {2,1}, I need no swaps as already min `bt` is there. I can add that condition to check, but still, it doesn't address the original problem really.

Comment: Yup.. I was just trying to give one wrong case.. btw..
I was thinking.. should not asnwer for {34,8,10,3,2,80,30,33,1} be 2 as bitonicity of {34,8,10,3,2,80,**1,30,33**} is 0? But from your algo It will come more than 2.

Comment: @KautsyaKanu Yes, that's correct. Actually this is one of those test cases where my algo doesn't give correct answer. I am trying to figure out the way but no luck:(

Comment: @KautsyaKanu btw, the above array you stated, it can be brought to `bt = 0` state by just doing 1 swap. Swap positions of 2 and 3.

Comment: yup.. I realised that.. Between 80 and 1.. right..

Comment: Can you provide a list of test cases with answer if any?

Comment: @VidorVistrom: Test case 1: a = {34,8,10,3,2,80,30,33,1}, min swaps = 1 ( swap 2 and 3)
Test case 2: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}: min swaps = 2 (swap 7 with 4 and 6 with 5)
Test case 3: {10,3,15,7,9,11}: min swaps = 0. `bt = 1` already.

Comment: Also are all the elements distinct? What if the case arises where two subsequent elements are same?

Comment: @VidorVistrom: All elements are distinct. But in my opinion, I think you want to ask if two adjacent elements are distinct, right? All adjacent elements are distinct. Let me put this in edit as well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you found this question on some online judge like codechef, please provide a link!

Comment: @VidorVistrom: I was asked this question in an interview last week. Trying to get a solution for it since then! Although the interviewer was pleased with my above algo, but he told that my algo will still fail for most test cases. He was also unsure of the perfect solution. But he did promote me for the next round though! :)

Comment: Incidentally, they were too trying to implement similar technique for one of the trading data analysis pattern.

Comment: Hey can you provide more test cases? I think I have found an O(n) algorithm, just want to make sure it does not leak in some cases!

Comment: @VidorVistrom: Added few more test cases in the question itself.

Comment: @VidorVistrom Hey! I was just wondering if you were able to pass the test cases with your first draft of algo. If its possible, can you please share your code with me? I will try to take it from there if I can.

Comment: @CodeHunter Sorry for late reply. My algorithm was not able to pass all the test cases. Just a few of them. I will keep trying and shall update as soon as possible

Comment: @VidorVistrom: Thanks a lot! Let me know if I can help. Moreover, I also found something on my side but yet to test. Will share with you in case I am able to verify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029024/how-to-determine-if-a-sequence-is-bitonic

Comment: @mikep..not at all. He is not asking what is bitonicity. That question doesn't solve the OPs situation at any instances. Or am I missing something?

Comment: [1:] isn\`t bitonicity a vector, given the definition? [2:] Assuming that it is actually a number with the greatest absolute value over the said vector, how exactly do you get 0 given the first example? `a = {34,8,10,2,3,80,30,33,1}` ⇒ `bt = {0,–1,0,–1,0,1,0,1,0}` ⇒ `max(abs(bt)) = 1`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: `bt` is the final value we get after the whole array traversal is completed. So, in this case, it is 0.

Comment: @mikep: not at all. That question just tells you how to make an array bitonic. This is different.

Comment: Google suggests some terminology, in case it helps. Without loss of generality, you can replace each element in `a` with it's rank, so `a` is just a permutation. You are then trying to compute the Cayley distance from `a` to the set of alternating permutations.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko: Can you please elaborate if possible? Might be helpful! Or just provide link if you can?

Comment: @CodeHunter I did not find an algorithm; hopefully, this is still relevant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/permutations-any-implementation-of-the-cayley-distance. The first point is that you can think of `a` itself as a permutation.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko See, Alternating permutations is the first thing I thought of. But I realized  that it will be just one specific case where swapping only with adjacent will occur. That will lead to a solution but will not give the minimum. Another way I thought of was making all permutations possible of the given order and calculate that Cayley Distance. But imagine 100 elements. That would be around 9.33262154439441526817E+157 calculations!

Comment: @VidorVistrom Right, calculating Caylay distance directly is not a way to go) If we identify `a` with a permutation though, we are looking for the shortest distance from `a` to any alternating permutation; I do not mean permuting `a` by an alternating permutation. Anyway, this is already O(n log(n)) , not O(n) as per OP.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Alternating permutation is just one specific case of a bitonic array. It could go `{+, -, +, -, ...}` or it could also go `{+, -, -, -, +, -, +, +}`. Both cases have "minimum bitonicity" as defined in this question.

Comment: @darksky: just to clarify, there might be repeated elements in the array, but they would not be adjacent for sure. For e.g., `{1,3,1,3,1,3}` would be valid array but `{1,3,3,1,3,1}` won't be.

Comment: @CodeHunter Please use italicized words for definition  of terms only, and only once during their definition. Use bold for emphasis. What does "distinct adjacent" mean? Distinct alone means all elements are different, so necessarily two adjacent elements in an array of distinct integers are distinct.

Comment: @darksky: I don't think you understood the point here. An element in the array doesn't need to be distinct.

Comment: @CodeHunter oh I see. So the whole array is not distinct. Then how do you calculate bitonicity of the resulting array aftet a swap that results in adjacent elements being the same? You dont have a condition on what happens when `a[i] == a[i - 1]`.

Comment: @darksky: Why are you confusing it? How is `a[i] == a[i-1]` a possibility here when it is given that **adjacent elements** of the array are **distinct**? For more details, please see test case 4.

Comment: After you swap. For example `a={1, 3, 4, 1}`. This is valid according to your rule. We swap 3 with the last 1. Then we need to calculate bitonicity, but that is no longer possible.

Comment: @darksky: Yeah. That means that is not a valid swap then.

Comment: Then this will make this problem extremely complicated, as now swapping is only sometimes valid whereas when the array as a whole is distinct, swapping is always valid. I'd say either define bt_array to take value 0 when `a[i] = a[i - 1]` or make them all distinct. Already it's a hard problem, I doubt your version can be solved in polynomial time, let alone linear time.

Comment: Also, if your rule is to not allow certain swaps that results in array not having a defined bitonicity, please edit your question and explicitly state it there.

Comment: @darksky: Yeah, for that matter, I think we can define one more condition where `bt_array[i] = bt_array[i-1]` if `a[i] == a[i-1]`. Let me edit the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Okay. Note that with this rule, you are no longer constrained to have a guarantee that adjacent elements in the initial array are distinct. Now they can be the same, and that drastically changes the problem.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: I will correct it. Actually my algo stated above gave me 2, so I posted it. Anyways, thanks for pointing it. I will correct it.

Comment: @CodeHunter one of your examples is incorrect! `{1,7,8,9,10,13,11}: current bt = 4: Swap 1,7 and 8,9 : minSwaps = 2` actually has **minSwaps = 1**, as swapping e.g. 1 and 8 (or, say, 7 and 9) immediately gives **bt = 0**. Stand by, I\`ve formulated and almost proved a set of theorems stating that the target number of swaps is a function of initial **bt**, regardless of **a**. Will post the answer ASAP.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: That's interesting. So we would be needing `a` to just point out the first eligible swapping elements then?

Comment: @CodeHunter we\`d be needing **a** to compute **bt**. Once it\`s done, **a** is no more necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## URGENT UPDATE: T3 does not hold!

Consider **α = [0, 7, 8, 3, 4, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 5]**. There is no **S<sub>ij</sub>(α)** that can lower **|B(α)|** by more than 2.

Thinking on amendments to the method…

### Warning

This solution only works when there are no array elements that are equal.

Feel free to propose generalizations by editing the answer.

Go straight to **Conclusion** if you want to skip the boring part.

### Introduction

Let`s define the swap operator **S<sub>ij</sub>** over the array **a**:

**S<sub>ij</sub>(a) : [… a<sub>i</sub>, … a<sub>j</sub>, …] → [… a<sub>j</sub>, … a<sub>i</sub>, …]   ∀i, j ∈ [0; |a|) ∩ ℤ : i ≠ j**

Let`s also refer to the bitonicity as **B(a)**, and define it more formally:

[image]

The obvious facts:

1. Swaps are symmetric:

   **S<sub>ij</sub>(a) = S<sub>ji</sub>(a)**
2. Two swaps are independent if their target positions don`t intersect:

   **S<sub>ij</sub>(S<sub>kl</sub>(a)) = S<sub>kl</sub>(S<sub>ij</sub>(a))   ∀i, j, k, l : {i, j} ∩ {k, l} = ∅**
3. Two 2-dependent swaps undo one another:

   **S<sub>ij</sub>(S<sub>ij</sub>(a)) = a**
4. Two 1-dependent swaps abide to the following:

   **S<sub>jk</sub>(S<sub>ij</sub>(a)) = S<sub>ij</sub>(S<sub>ik</sub>(a)) = S<sub>ik</sub>(S<sub>jk</sub>(a))**
5. Bitonicity difference is always even  for equally sized arrays:

   **(B(a) – B(a')) mod 2 = 0   ∀a, a' : |a| = |a'|**

   Naturally, **∀i : 0 < i < |a|**,

   **B([a<sub>i–1</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>]) – B([a'<sub>i–1</sub>, a'<sub>i</sub>]) = sgn(a<sub>i</sub> – a<sub>i–1</sub>) – sgn(a'<sub>i</sub> – a'<sub>i–1</sub>)**,

   which can either be 1 – 1 = 0, or 1 – –1 = 2, or –1 – 1 = –2, or –1 – –1 = 0, and any number of ±2`s and 0`s summed yield an even result.

   **N.B.:** this is only true if all elements in **a** differ from one another, same with **a'**!

### Theorems

#### [T1]   **|B(S<sub>ij</sub>(a)) – B(a)| ≤ 4   ∀a, S<sub>ij</sub>(a)**

Without loss of generality, let`s assume that:

- **0 < i, j < |a| – 1**
- **j – i ≥ 2**
- **a<sub>i–1</sub> < a<sub>i+1</sub>**
- **a<sub>j–1</sub> < a<sub>j+1</sub>**

Depending on **a<sub>i</sub>**, 3 cases are possible:

1. **a<sub>i–1</sub> < a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>i+1</sub>: sgn(a<sub>i</sub> – a<sub>i–1</sub>) + sgn(a<sub>i+1</sub> – a<sub>i</sub>) = 1 + 1 = 2**
2. **a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>i–1</sub> < a<sub>i+1</sub>: sgn(a<sub>i</sub> – a<sub>i–1</sub>) + sgn(a<sub>i+1</sub> – a<sub>i</sub>) = –1 + 1 = 0**
3. **a<sub>i–1</sub> < a<sub>i+1</sub> < a<sub>i</sub>: sgn(a<sub>i</sub> – a<sub>i–1</sub>) + sgn(a<sub>i+1</sub> – a<sub>i</sub>) = 1 + –1 = 0**

When altering **a<sub>i</sub>** and leaving all other elements of **a** intact, **|B(a') – B(a)| ≤ 2** (where **a'** is the resulting array, for which the above 3 cases also apply), since no other terms of **B(a)** changed their value, except those two from the 1-neighborhood of **a<sub>i</sub>**.

**S<sub>ij</sub>(a)** implies what`s described above to happen twice, once for **a<sub>i</sub>** and once for **a<sub>j</sub>**.

Thus, **|B(S<sub>ij</sub>(a)) – B(a)| ≤ 2 + 2 = 4**.

Analogously, for each of the corners and **j – i = 1** the max. possible delta is 2, which is ≤ 4.

Finally, this straightforwardly extrapolates to **a<sub>i–1</sub> > a<sub>i+1</sub>** and **a<sub>j–1</sub> > a<sub>j+1</sub>**.

QED

#### [T2]   **∀a : |B(a)| ≥ 2   ∃S<sub>ij</sub>(a) : |B(S<sub>ij</sub>(a))| = |B(a)| – 2**

{proof in progress, need to sleep}

#### [T3]   **∀a : |B(a)| ≥ 4   ∃S<sub>ij</sub>(a) : |B(S<sub>ij</sub>(a))| = |B(a)| – 4**

{proof in progress, need to sleep}

### Conclusion

From **T1**, **T2** and **T3**, the minimal number of swaps needed to minimize **|B(a)|** equals:

**⌊|B(a)| / 4⌋ + ß**,

where **ß** equals 1 if **|B(a)| mod 4 ≥ 2**, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Really appreciate the effort! +1. Right now, I couldn't find any countercases but I encourage the people related to this question to please verify this. 
Also, can you please explain the assumption for **T1**, especially the last 2? There can be a case when `a[i–1] > a[i+1]` and `a[j–1] < a[j+1]` and vice versa. I conclude that in that case, `B(a)` will cancel out eventually and the **T1** would still hold. Can you please identify my conclusion on this?

Comment: @CodeHunter exactly. There can be a situation when there\`s a +2 in the first place and –2 in the second (or vice versa), so they add nothing to the final sum. [UPD:] Adding proofs…

Comment: @CodeHunter But I thought if its for industrial practice, you must know the exact swaps. As you mentioned " trading data analysis pattern ", don't you want a mechanism that could tell you the exact swaps?

Comment: @CodeHunter sorry for breaking my promise to prove this today. Working on it. The main idea for **T2** is: to reach at least **B(a) = ±2**, **a** must have a chain of at least 3 consecutively incr. or decr. values (bitonicity chain **± → ±**). Dealing with 4-chains (**± → ± → ±**) or more is simple, as we may take any 2 non-edge values and swap them (**± → ∓ → ±**), thus disrupting the chain. So, what\`s left to prove in **T2** is that **∓ → ± → ± → ∓** bitonicity chains (let\`s call them N-chains as they resemble N-s if drawn in slashes: **/\\/**) are also capable of being properly disrupted.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: Cool. I have actually tested the above logic you gave on most of test cases but failed with none. I think the idea is correct!