# how to check if a sequence of size n is first monotonically increasing and then monotonically decreasing with n-1 comparisons

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose I have a sequence represented by an array of n numbers.

Is it possible to check if that sequence is monotonically increasing and then monotonically decreasing with n-1 comparisons?

I have tried to use this link [How to determine if a sequence is bitonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029024/how-to-determine-if-a-sequence-is-bitonic), but I feel it doesn't lead me to an answer to my problem.

Comment: I can't help but suspect that this depends on whether the sequences are *strictly* monotonic.

Comment: Compare 2 and 2 elements from the sequence, as long as they are increasing you're in the first part. Once you get your first decreasing pair, you're in the second part and you should now only get decreasing results. If you end up getting another increase, the answer is "no, it does not follow your pattern".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: what do you mean by "compare 2 and 2 elements"?  Is it a typo or copy'paste problem for "compare 2 elements" or "compare two adjacent elements"?  Or something else?  The rest sounds about right — what I was thinking.

Comment: Compare element 1 with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4, etc. That's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is homework question, so here's a fancy/confusing pointer version. :-)

Does at most `n-1` comparisons (`p` goes from `&s[0]` to `s[n-1]`) between the elements of the array -- `O(n)`.

Does up to `2n+1` comparisons overall.

```
int is_incdec(int *s, int n) {
    int *p = &s[0];
    int *last = &s[n-1];
    while (p != last && *p < *(p+1)) p++;
    while (p != last && *p > *(p+1)) p++;
    return p == last;
}
```

Comment: *Technically* you have a lot more comparisons than `n - 1` because of `p != last` and `p == last`.

Comment: hmm... you're right :-) it's `O(n)`, which I believe was the implied requirement. I'm also only comparing elements `n-1` times; the remainder is just to check the bounds of the array

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure `O(n)` would *not* be a valid answer, since that is trivial. However, I suspect the question should be more precise: "At most `n-1` comparisons *between elements of the sequence*".

Comment: Well... "at most `n-1` in total" is impossible. You'll need to do at least some other comparison (e.g. check if you've reached the end of the array). :)

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the total number of compares, both between elements and testing if in the array range, code could temporarily alter the array.

```
bool up_down(int *x, size_t n) {
  int right = x[n-1];
  x[n-1] = INT_MIN;
  int *up = x;
  while (up[0] < up[1]) {
    up++;
  }
  x[n-1] = right; // restore

  int left = x[0];
  x[0] = INT_MIN;
  int *down = x + n - 1;
  while (down[0] < down[-1]) {
    down--;
  }
  x[0] = left; // restore

  return up == down;

  // or per EOF comment to avoid a last "compare"
  return !(up - down);
}
```

> Is it possible to check if that sequence is monotonically increasing and then monotonically decreasing with n-1 comparisons?

I do not think so if all compares are counted:  The above code needs a few more (2?) than `n-1` compares and does not do well when <strike>`n < 3`</strike> `n < 2`, but is the basis for a reduced compare count.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code fails to conform to the `n-1` limit IFF the sequence is completely monotonic, which is trivially the case for `n < 3`. Also, `up == down` could be replaced by `!(down - up)`.

Comment: @EOF, Yes I can see how to get within a few more than `n-1`, but `n-1` looks unobtainable.  Best I can do so far.  It would reason that at least `n-1` compares amongst the elements needed and than _at least_ one more to know when to end.

Comment: @EOF - I like your  `!(up - down)` idea.

Comment: Wow! This is quite clever! Only downside is when translating into machine code, `up == down` becomes your `non-comparison` :-P so while technically you can argue that in `C` you didn't write any comparison...

Comment: I haven't checked too closely, but it seems that your code will only correctly identify sequences that obey the property. For non-conforming sequences you may run into problems, since your `while` loops are unbounded. e.g. if your sequence is {1, 2, 3} and the following memory positions are {99, 0}, you'll count 4 `up`.

Comment: @JoãoNeto while loop are not unbounded.  With `x[n-1] = INT_MIN;`, `while (up[0] < up[1]) {` stop at or before the end of the array as `up[0]` cannot be less than `INT_MIN`.  So the loop stops before going off array end.  Similar with ` while (down[0] < down[-1])`

Comment: indeed :) i take back what i said